# matrix alignment problem

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am not able to align the righthand side matrix.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}   
 \[
    \left[ 
    \begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
    & \vdots &  \\
     \begin{array}{c}
          \mbox{\LARGE {Q}}
      \end{array} & 0 & \begin{array}{c}
             \mbox{\LARGE {O}}
      \end{array}  \\
      \begin{matrix} \cdots &  0& u_0  \end{matrix} & \begin{array}{c}
                           u_{-1}\\
                           d_0\\
                           l_1
                          \end{array} & \begin{matrix} c_0 & 0 & \cdots \end{matrix}\\
    \mbox{\LARGE {O}} & 0 &  \begin{array}{c}
                                       \mbox{\LARGE {S}}
                                      \end{array} \\
    &  \vdots & \\
    \end{array}\right]
    \left[\begin{array}{c}
    x_-\\
    x_0\\
    x_+
    \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}
    y_-\\
    y_0\\
    y_+
    \end{array}\right] 
    \] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not able to align the righthand side matrix.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! how is your question related to `latex3` ( i don't see any to it specific code in your code fragment)? matrix is centered in text width. what is the problem? please, extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{<class name>}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you also should add document class and preamble ... end also correct code. it has error (`missing \endgroup`)

Comment: Code is correct..it is working in texmaker..

Answer (score 3):

this is more comment than an answer ...

after cleaning up your code to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\begin{document}
 \[
    \begin{bmatrix}
        &                   &       & \vdots    &       &                   &           \\
        & \mbox{\LARGE {Q}} &       &   0       &       & \mbox{\LARGE {O}} &           \\
        &                   &       &   u_1     &       &                   &           \\
\cdots  &   0               &  u_0  &   d_0     &  c_0  &   0               &  \cdots   \\
        &                   &       &   l_1     &       &                   &           \\
       & \mbox{\LARGE {O}}  &       &   0       &       & \mbox{\LARGE {Q}} &           \\
        &                   &       & \vdots    &       &                   &           \\
     \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x_-\\
    x_0\\
    x_+
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    y_-\\
    y_0\\
    y_+
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

i obtain

[image]

which is as i see perfectly aligned.

note: i use `\begin{bmatrix}` instead your construct `\lef[\begin{array}` and remove all inner matrices. code gives the same result, however it is much shorter and clearer.